# how to Parse user-selected data in an activity

Tags: android, json

i am trying to parse the json data,in my application,i have 2 dropdown box from which user select the country name to which he wants to convert the data.and the amount he want to convert is passed into the url. and i am using AsyncHttpClient lib to read the data,before using it on different api it work perfectly fine ,but when i change my api it start run the failure method.first i thought i passed wrong url.,but on toast i get to knw i am passing correct url of the api.

what is the problem can anyone tell me..??

Thanking you in advance.

```
private String API_URL = "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/";
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    final String url1 = API_URL + t1.toString() + "/" + t2.toString() + "/"
                            + usdValue.getText().toString() + "/" + "json";

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url1.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (!usdValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

                        client.get(url1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "unsuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onFinish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onStart();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "start",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                Log.i("CHACHING", "HTTP Sucess");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                    Double usds = Double.valueOf(usdValue.getText()
                                            .toString());
                                    Double rate = jsonObj.getDouble("to_amount");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            String.valueOf(rate), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    double the_result = usds * rate;

                                    ConvertedFrom.setText(usdValue.getText()
                                            .toString()
                                            + " "
                                            + ConvertedFromCurr.getSelectedItem()
                                                    .toString() + " = ");
                                    ConvertedTo.setText(String.valueOf(the_result)
                                            + " "
                                            + ConvertedToCurr.getSelectedItem()
                                                    .toString());

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter a Amount value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for cross domain api calls you must use jsonp.

This is an example in javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/EUR/GBP/1/",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.GBP);

        }

});
```